# Mongodb query nested item inside nested, also $match with one of nested child property

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

my document structure is:

```
db={
  "booking": [
    {
      "id": "adfaldjf",
      "cart": [
        {
          "id": "sdsadadadd",
          "product": "X-Man 4",
          "timeSlots": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "spots": 10
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "sdsadadadd",
          "product": "Blue 1",
          "timeSlots": [
            {
              "id": 8,
              "spots": 3
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my search filters are:

**bookingId: adfaldjf**

**timeSlotId: 8**

the result should be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "cart": {
      "id": "sdsadadadd",
      "product": "Blue 1",
      "timeSlots": {
        "id": 8,
        "spots": 3
      }
    },
    "id": "adfaldjf"
  }
]
```

Comment: what should happen if `timeslot.id=8` exists in more than 1 members of `cart`?
you want cart to be an array with the matching slots or just 1 member that match?

Comment: @Takis_ it's unique

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- match id
- double unwind and match

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70636776-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$id", "adfaldjf"]}}}, 
 {"$unwind":"$cart"},
 {"$unwind":"$cart.timeSlots"}, 
 {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$cart.timeSlots.id", 8]}}}])
```

Query2

- local way without unwind
- map and filter the timeslot to be 8
- filter to remove the nulls (carts without this `timeslot=8`)
- keep document if found at least one cart that has timeslot=8

*it could be 2 nested filters, but you want to change from array to `{}` so map is used to change it (i mean not keep an array with 1 document but keep only 1 document), and query became a bit bigger

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70636776-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$id", "adfaldjf"]}}},
 {"$set":
  {"cart":
   {"$map":
    {"input":"$cart",
     "in":
     {"$let":
      {"vars":
       {"slot":
        {"$first":
         {"$filter":
          {"input":"$$c.timeSlots",
           "cond":{"$eq":["$$t.id", 8]},
           "as":"t"}}}},
       "in":
       {"$cond":
        ["$$slot", {"$mergeObjects":["$$c", {"timeSlots":"$$slot"}]},
         null]}}},
     "as":"c"}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"cart":
   {"$first":
    {"$filter":{"input":"$cart", "cond":{"$ne":["$$this", null]}}}}}},
 {"$match":{"$expr":{"$ne":[{"$type":"$cart"}, "missing"]}}}])
```